# Is there a sequential space that is compact but not sequentially compact?

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ is

- sequential if every sequentially closed set is closed,
- compact, if every open cover has a finite subcover,
- sequentially compact, if every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Any first-countable space is sequential. Any first-countable compact space is sequentially compact.

The typical example $I^I$ with $I = [0,1]$ for a compact not sequentially compact space is not sequential. For such a counterexample it is necessary that $X$ is not first-countable.

The database version of Steen-Seebach [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Compact%2BSequential%2B%7ESequentially%20Compact) does not provide such an example.

Comment: You mean covering compact but not sequentially compact?

Comment: No, $X$ should be sequential, covering compact and not sequentially compact. I add the definitions.

Comment: Being covering compact is equivalent to being sequentially compact.

Comment: What is your definition of "covering compact"?

Comment: The exact same definition you gave above.

Comment: In first-countable spaces it only holds compact $\Rightarrow$ sequentially compact $\Leftrightarrow$ countably compact. In second-countable spaces all these three compactness properties are equivalent.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests the ordinal space $[0, \omega_1)$

Comment: $\omega_1 = [0, \omega_1)$ is first-countable, sequentially compact and not compact. (Also, $\omega_1 + 1 = [0, \omega_1]$ is compact and sequentially compact but not sequential.)

Comment: misread the question, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is compact and sequential, it is in particular countably compact. And countable compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent for sequential spaces (I do believe we need at least $T_1$ here, but if your compact space is Hausdorff this is no problem).

As noted in the comments, a sequential and sequentially compact Hausdorff space need not be compact (we only get to countable compactness; the Lindelöfness has to be assumed to get compactness), as shown by $\omega_1$. But from compactness we do get sequential compactness for sequential spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the hint for the equivalence of countable compactness and sequential compactness for sequential spaces ($T_1$ is not necessary).

Comment: For a proof of "countably compact + sequential $\Rightarrow$ sequentially compact" (without $T_1$) see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658362/is-there-a-countably-compact-sequential-non-t-2-space-that-is-not-sequentially/1733040#1733040).

Answer (score 0):

Today, the [pi-Base search you suggested](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Compact%2BSequential%2B%7ESequentially%20Compact) gives a proof that all compact and sequential spaces are sequentially compact, noting first that [compact spaces are countably compact by definition](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000001), and then that [sequential and countably compact spaces are sequentially compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000223). The latter is proven in [your answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1733040).

Answer (score -1):

The equivalence of countable compactness and sequential compactness for sequential spaces is true only when the space is $T_1$.

I have seen the [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658362/is-there-a-countably-compact-sequential-non-t-2-space-that-is-not-sequentially/1733040#1733040), which has a bug and the end part, because   $x$ being cluster point of $(x_n)_{n\ge N}$ is not always true, and
if the space is $T_1$, you can say that.

The condition of $T_1$ is necessary

Comment: What you are claiming in incorrect.  The proof in the link is fine and there is no need to assume the space is $T_1$.  $x$ is chosen to be a cluster point of the sequence $(x_n)$.  Such a cluster point exists because the space is countably compact by assumption.  This is in fact one of the characterizations of countably compact spaces.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countably_compact_space.