# Special neighborhoods for distinct points in a first countable and compact space?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I was reading the following proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass thorem (Theorem 1.1.17 from Abraham and Marsden's *Foundations of Mechanics*):

> *If $S$ is a first countable and compact space, then every sequence has a convergent subsequence.*
>
> ***Proof.*** Supose $\{u_n\}$ contains no convergent subsequences. Then we may assume that all points are distinct. Each $u_n$ has a neighborhood $\mathcal O_n$ that contains no other $u_m$. From 1.1.13, $\{u_n\}$ is closed so that $\{\mathcal O_n\}$ together with $\mathcal C\{u_N\}$ [this denotes the complement of $\{u_n\}$] forms an open covering of $S$ with no finite subcovering.

I understand the proof, except one thing. **Why can $u_n$ have neighborhoods $\mathcal O_n$ as claimed in the proof?** I don't see how it follows from first ountability and/or compactness.

---

In the book, 1.1.13 is the following:

> *Let $S$ be a first countable space and $A\subset S$. Then $u\in cl(A)$ iff there is a sequence of points of $A$ that converge to $u$.*

---

I wrote about this to Ralph Abraham, and he forwarded it to Ratiu Tudor, who confirmed that the definition of compactness must have included Hausdorff condition too. In that case, Brian's answer below, answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{B_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable base at $u_n$; without loss of generality we may assume that $B_{k+1}\subseteq B_k$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. Now suppose that every open nbhd of $u_n$ contains some $u_m$ with $m\ne n$. Then each open nbhd of $u_n$ must contain infinitely many points of the sequence. (Why?) Thus, we can choose $m_0$ such that $u_{m_0}\in B_0$, $u_{m_1}$ such that $m_1>m_0$ and $u_{m_1}\in B_1$, and so on: that is, we can recursively choose a subsequence $\langle u_{m_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $u_{m_k}\in B_k$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. But then for each $\ell\in\Bbb N$ we have $u_{m_k}\in B_k\subseteq B_\ell$ for all $k\ge \ell$, so $\langle u_{m_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $u_n$, contrary to the assumption that $\langle u_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has no convergent subsequence. This contradiction shows that $u_n$ must have an open nbhd that contains no other point of the sequence.

Comment: I was thinking about the "Why?". For all I know, there can be the case when $B_k$'s are such that they become "eventually constant" to some $B_{k_0}$, containing a distinct $u_m$, such that any open neighborhood of $u_m$ contains $u_n$. In such a case, I don't see any way to ensure existence of any other $u_l$ in $B_{k_0}$.

Comment: @Atom: Yes, we do need to assume that the space is at least $T_1$; I meant to say something about that and then forgot. I suspect that when Abraham & Marsden say *compact*, they mean *compact Hausdorff*; this is not unusual.

Comment: Oh. But in the text, they define (1.1.16): *Let $S$ be a topological space. Then $S$ is called* ***compact*** *iff for every covering of $S$ by open sets $U_\alpha$ there is a finite subcovering.* They have no mention of Hasudorff.

Comment: Maybe they forgot to include the Hausdorff hypothesis in their formulation of the B-W theorem. I'll be satisfied if you can confirm that Hausdorff is a **required** assumption for B-W.

Comment: @Atom: I’ll have to think about whether the B-W theorem itself actually needs it, but the claim that was bothering you in their proof definitely does: I can easily come up with a first countable space and a sequence in it having no convergent subsequence for which that claim is false.

Comment: Oh. Thanks tons Brian! In the meantime, can you maybe point me to a "more correct" version of the B-W (with its proof, if possible)?

Comment: @Atom: The name *Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem* is usually applied to the theorem that every bounded sequence in $\Bbb R^n$ has a convergent subsequence. The result here is that every first countable, compact space is [sequentially compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space), and it’s usually proved with the additional assumption that the space is $T_1$. However, an even stronger result can be proved without that assumption: every countably compact [sequential] space is sequentially compact. See [this answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

Comment: I think you added the wrong link for 'thins answer'. I was expecting an SE answer. (I commend your patience in explaining things!)

Comment: @Atom: You’re right: that link was supposed to be attached to *sequential space*. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658362/is-there-a-countably-compact-sequential-non-t-2-space-that-is-not-sequentially/1733040#1733040) is the correct link for the stronger result.

Comment: The proof as you have presented, will relies on countable choice **twice**. First in choosing the $u_{m_i}$'s, and second, finally choosing the neighbourhoods $\{\mathcal O_n\}$ (in your proof, you only shown that such a neighborhood exists for each $u_n$, but not the existence of a family). Is there a way occurring to you that might avoid countable choice?

Comment: @Atom: Not at the moment, and I’d guess that there isn’t one. It’s not something that concerns me at all: a great deal of topology depends on at least weaker forms of the axiom of choice — the Tikhonov product theorem is actually equivalent to it — and in any case I consider it entirely unproblematic.

Comment: Okay. Don't mind my silly questions :) This is my first brush with topology.

Comment: @Atom: No problem!